# Retrieve resource working hours from Project Server via PSI

Tags: sharepoint, project-server, psi

I'm working with SharePoint and ProjectServer 2007 via PSI.

I need to retrieve the working hours of an employee in a project during a date range but I can't find a way to do it. The closest data I've gotten is the **RES_ACT_WORK** from Project.ReadProject(), but this is a total value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the way to retrieve it!!!

[Statusing.ReadStatusTimephasedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcstatusing.statusing.readstatustimephaseddata%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

---

*Edit*:

This method return the statusing data for the currently logged user. If the user is the project owner, it will get the data for every assigned resource. Otherwise, only the user's data will be returned.

In order to retrieve the whole of the data (every project and every resource), the `[PSI impersonation][2]` must be used.

But that is not possible in my case, so I am developing a `[PSI extension][3]` to expose the information I need and `[custom permission][4]` to control access to it.

```
  [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa974347(office.12).aspx
  [3]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb428837(office.12).aspx
  [4]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa974255(v=office.12).aspx
```

*NB: I cannot post more than one link yet* :P